# What would be suitable entry source for my journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, automationstudio, email-studio

Problem Statement:

I have to inject records into the journey whenever a customer's status is upgraded to higher from lower. We have a three-status record.

Priority  Status

1         Silver

2         Gold

3         Platinum

Whenever customer status is changed from Silver to Gold, Silver to Platinum, Gold to Platinum then they should receive an email

Which entry source is suitable?
I was looking for two options.

Option 1 -> Salesforce data
On record update to Gold, I can send them an email but the problem is I want to send them an email only when the record is updated from Silver to Gold, with this option I am sending email even when record is updated from Platinum to Gold

Option 2 -> SQL Query and inject data into data extension from the Synchronised data extension
But in SQL query I can not check the previous status was silver and the current status is gold.
I can only fetch the record whose current status is gold

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are better ways of doing this but something I've done is use [field tracking history](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tracking_field_history.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) in Salesforce to track changes for a particular field. I then have a Salesforce report set up to return Contacts for whom the value for the field has changed. The report output has columns for Old Value and New Value. Example:

[image]

I then sync this report to Marketing Cloud and query the resulting data extension from there.